# dealing with character(0) returning from str_extract_all

Tags: r, stringr, unnest

During data wrangling, I would like to clean a column extracting only a specific pattern.

```
mytib <- tibble(
  a = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  b = c("aaa876", NA, "auy987 iuy876", "alsdjkf a", "1234 abc987"))

x <- mytib %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(b = stringr::str_extract_all(b, "[a-z]{3}[0-9]{3}")) %>% 
  unnest(b)

# results:
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#      a b     
#     <dbl> <chr> 
# 1     1 aaa876
# 2     2 NA    
# 3     3 auy987
# 4     3 iuy876
# 5     5 abc987
```

Instead I would like to get:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# a b     
#     <dbl> <chr> 
#  1     1 aaa876
#  2     2 NA    
#  3     3 auy987
#  4     3 iuy876
#  5     4 NA    
#  6     5 abc987
```

It seems that because the row (4, "alsdjkf") didn't fit the pattern, **str_stract_all** returned "character(0)" and the **unnest** function ripped it off the final result.

Does anybody knows how could I get to the desired result in any other way, or how could I handle the "character(0)" so unnest would preserve the row where a == 4?

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve in more detail?

Comment: I want a tibble keeping all values from column a from the original tibble, where column b  should be 1) or the string from the pattern (1 or more strings, 1 by row), 2) or NA, when the pattern don't occur.

Comment: the code I'm using works when all rows or have one or many patterns, or has NA. When any row has "anything" but the pattern, the str_extract returns character(0) which makes unnest exclude the row from the final result. So... treating str_extract result before calling unnest, would work, but I couldn't find out how to. For example: x <- mytib %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(b = stringr::str_extract_all(b, "[a-z]{3}[0-9]{3}")) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(b = if_else(identical(b, character(0), NA_character_, as.character(b)))) %>% 
  unnest(b) .... doesn't work

Comment: So it seems to me I am not knowing how to handle character(0) return from str_extract_all.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `keep_empty = TRUE` in `unnest`:

```
x <- mytib %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(b = stringr::str_extract_all(b, "[a-z]{3}[0-9]{3}")) %>% 
  unnest(b, keep_empty = TRUE)

x
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>       a b     
#>   <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1     1 aaa876
#> 2     2 NA    
#> 3     3 auy987
#> 4     3 iuy876
#> 5     4 NA    
#> 6     5 abc987
```