# Remove character(0) as R argument in list, data frame

Tags: r, character

I am desperate, I tried all I could and nothing happened I tried everything but I cannot get rid of character(0) when I paste columns together. What happens is the following:
I have a dataframe, where I have a long string and I need to extract certain words:
So I do:
This is my dataframe x

```
V1                 
N_W5B, ABC, JJJ    
B_W5B, ABC, JJJ
```

Then I do

```
x$column.1 = str_extract_all(x$V1, "N_([A-Z][0-9])[A-Z]")
x$column.2 = str_extract_all(x$V1, "B_([A-Z][0-9])[A-Z]")
```

And I get

```
V1                 column.1        column.2
N_W5B, ABC, JJJ    N_W5B           charachter(0)
B_W5B, ABC, JJJ    charachter(0)   B_W5B
```

Then I paste them together but is already too late because charachter(0) is already there so I get:

```
x$paste.column<-paste(x$column.1,x$column.2,sep=",")
```

```
V1                 column.1        column.2       paste.column
N_W5B, ABC, JJJ    N_W5B           charachter(0)  N_W5B,charachter(0)
B_W5B, ABC, JJJ    charachter(0)   B_W5B          charachter(0),B_W5B
```

```
x$paste.column<- gsub("character(0)", " ", x$paste.column)
```

And is been a nightmare so far because nothing works to remove the charachter(0)
Please help! Much appreciated

Comment: you could set simplfy = TRUE in your str_extract_all: `x$column.1 = stringr::str_extract_all(x$V1, "N_([A-Z][0-9])[A-Z]", simplify = T)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dealing with character(0) returning from str\_extract\_all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68410770/dealing-with-character0-returning-from-str-extract-all)

Comment: FYI: It doesn't return a string `character(0)`, but an empty character vector, that you'll need to take care of earlier as described by @VvdL

Comment: I get this, when I try with simplify = T, Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Comment: I saw the question, but unsure if means I need to use unnest

Comment: Oh gosh the question you pointed at I guess has the solution!! thank you so so much